# Average and Median of values of 4 columns for each row in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis

I have 4 columns, Col1,Col2,Col3 and Col4
I need to add 2 calculated column that get the Average and median of 4 values of those 4 columns from each row.
That's should be DAX,no need power query

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Average | Medin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 8 | 9 | 5 | 6.25 | 6.5 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Average = DIVIDE([Col1] + [Col2] + [Col3] + [Col4], 4)

Medin = MEDIANX({ [Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4] }, [Value])
```

Comment: What if I want to get dax stdev.s for the same situation

Comment: The same approach as `Medin`

Comment: Thanks Sam,It's working very well

Comment: What if I want make some filters,like the median of values more than 5 or 0.